# How to make pipeline fail immediately if any of its stages fail

Tags: shell, pipe

Suppose I have a pipeline

`reader | processor | writer`.

Seems that by default if `processor` or `writer` fail in the best case pipeline will fail only after reader will try to send data to processor.

I need the whole pipeline fail immediately if any of its stages fail. `set -eo pipefail` doesn't help.

Is this possible without some ugly workarounds? Seems like a natural thing to do that should be possible.

I've maid an example.

```
==> script <==
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -eo pipefail

trap "exit 1" ERR

./read | ./process | ./write

==> read <==
#! /usr/bin/env bash

seq 10 |
    while read line; do
        >&2 echo echoing $line
        echo $line
        sleep 2
    done

==> process <==

count=0
while read line; do
    echo processing $line
    count=$((count+1))
    if [[ $count == 1 ]]; then
        >&2 echo exiting...
        exit 1
    fi
done

==> write <==
#! /usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

Running this gives

```
echoing 1
exiting...
processing 1
echoing 2
```

Which makes obvious that script isn't ending until second line is echoed.

Comment: It seems like some combination of `set -o pipefail` and `trap 'exit 1' ERR` should do the trick.

Comment: @DopeGhoti It doesn't. See my example.